# Deploy a php webapp with git

Tags: php, git

I have developed a web-app in PHP, and I have been using GIT in my local machine to source-control it.

Now I have a simple hosting at MediaTemple, and I'd like to publish my site, just using GIT. So, how do I do that?

I thought about making `git init` at the server and cloning my local repo, after that, I could set my local repo remote origin to be the server one, so all I have to do to publish is a `git push origin master` on my local machine. But I am concerned about how many `.git/` folders and docs is my server going to have, and if that's dangerous for the server.

I only want to have the needed files there, read: source files, not source control files.

**Any suggestion? Or should I do it just this way and forget about hidden files?**

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There'll only one .git folder at root of the repo  on your server. I don't know about doc folder, do you mean your project doc or git doc?

Comment: can't you just pull the latest version (locally) and upload it? If you want to use git at server site you need git installed & access to the server's cli (via telnet, ssh, or directly on the machine) and pull the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do git push, your remote working directory is not updated (i.e. `git checkout` will not automatically happen on the remote side). You can use git pull from the remote side like:

```
ssh root@my-server 'cd /my/remote/repo && && git pull origin master'
```

if you have remote control of your server.

Comment: So I use my local (dev computer) as origin for the server, and pull from there? (I connect with ssh)